# Weird accents instead of spaces when typing - Windows10

Tags: windows-10

Sometimes when I'm typing, my computer will insert accents when I press the space bar. It only happens when the word has an accent, and then when I finish the word by pressing space, it will add another "standalone" accent instead of the space. If I follow the word with a dot, it will produce the accent and the dot.

So, for instance, if I wanted to type

```
Colégio X - perto do metrô.
```

I would get

```
Colégio´X - perto do metrô^.
```

I noticed that it only occurs in browser-based apps, such as Vivaldi, Chrome, and Obsidian. If I switch to, say, Notepad++, it stops, but returns as soon as I go back to the original app.

I can never predict when the problem will start. I always try to remember if I accidently pressed some combination of keys immediately before it starts, but apparently it is totally random. After a few minutes, it goes away by itself.

**Edit**:
I use Windows 10 updated to the last version (21H2). I tried different keyboards also, but the problem persists.

My keyboard layout is Portuguese (Brazil ABNT). To get an "à", I type ` and then "a". Just to be clear, my problem is not getting the accented letter, that is working fine. The problem is I'm getting an extra, unwanted accent at the end of the word.